# imul assembly instruction - one operand?

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication

I am using a run-time debugger.

EAX: 0000 0023
EDX: 5555 5556

```
imul edx
```

EAX: aaaa aac2
EDX: 0000 000b

I am utterly confused, and can't figure out how this multiply is working.  What's happening here? I notice in a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948058/problem-in-understanding-mul-imul-instructions-of-assembly-language) that  `imul ebx ; result in EDX:EAX` I don't understand the EDX:EAX notation though :/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When the one-operand form of `imul` is passed a 32 bit argument, it effectively means `EAX * src` where both `EAX` and the source operand are 32-bit registers or memory.

The product of two 32 bit values doesn't necessarily fit in 32 bits: the full multiply result can take up to 64 bits.  The high 32 bits of the answer will be written to the `EDX` register and the low 32 bits to the `EAX` register; this is represented with the `EDX:EAX` notation.

In your case with `imul edx`, you get `EDX:EAX = EAX * EDX`.  It's fine for the explicit source operand to be one of the implicit operands, even `EAX` to square into `EDX:EAX`.

---

If you only want the low 32 bits of the result, use the 2-operand form of `imul`; it runs faster and doesn't have any implicit operands (so you can use whatever registers are most convenient).

`imul ecx, esi` does `ecx *= esi` like you'd expect, without touching `EAX` or `EDX`.  It's like C where `unsigned x=...;` `x *= y;` has the same width for the result as the inputs.

`imul` also has an immediate form: `imul ecx, ebx, 1234` does `ecx = ebx * 1234`.  Many assemblers will accept `imul ecx, 1234` as short-hand for `imul ecx, ecx, 1234`.

---

These 32x32 => 32-bit forms of `imul` work correctly for signed or unsigned; the results of one-operand `mul` and `imul` only differ in the upper half (in `EDX`), not the low-half `EAX` output.

See [Intel's instruction reference manual entry for `imul`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/IMUL).

Comment: What happens when the register given to `imul` is `eax`? Does it still do the same thing? What if you give it something other than `eax` or `edx`, like `eax` for example?

Comment: There are many forms of the imul instruction. The form that takes a single 32bit argument (memory or register) always returns the result in the EDX:EAX pair.