# Understanding signed and unsigned mulitplication of an N-bit register using an operand of another size

Tags: assembly, x86-64, multiplication

I'm learning x86-64 assembly using online exercises on OST2's website.

All the exercise questions in regards to multiplication are confusing me.

> ```
> mov rax, 0x89204E764CB58DF0
> mov esp, 0xF627BAE4
> mul esp
> ```
>
> Question: What value is stored in edx:eax after the code is ran?
> Answer: The correct value in edx:eax after this code executes was 0x49C25E0D7A62C9C0

I can't understand how they have this result. My attempt was to just do the obvious of taking `0x89204E764CB58DF0` and multiplying it by `0xF627BAE4`, then only accounting for the 32 right bits (as I believe `edx:eax` is for 32 bit).

My result was `0x7A62C9C0`, which is half right - that's supposed to be the other half of the correct answer. So I thought.. maybe I should account for the entire 64 bits? No - that makes my result `0x3B83FB257A62C9C0` - the first 32 bits are wrong.

How can I better understand multiplication (signed and unsigned) in ASM? The site provides answers for the questions, but I don't want to be spoonfed but rather understand what's going on instead.

Comment: That's a pretty weird example, using `esp` like that. Anyway, your mistake seems to be not looking at the entire 64-bit result (i.e. `edx:eax`), and not disregarding the upper 32 bits of `rax` which are irrelevant for the multiplication. `4CB58DF0 * F627BAE4 = 49C25E0D7A62C9C0`

Comment: @Michael I agree - the example is weird (and the usage of `esp` rather than using `r9`-`r16` or even a stack variable rather than this.. questionable code), but indeed it caught me off-guard. Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: `edx:eax` is two consecutive 32-bit dwords which form a 64-bit qword. Using `esp` for arbitrary arithmetic is really unusual.

Comment: `edx:eax` is a pair of 64-bit regs, but the *inputs* to `imul r/m32` are both 32-bit; that's *why* the output is only 64-bit (sum of the input bit-widths).  Also, when you say *the first 32 bits are wrong*, perhaps you're talking about this *high* 32 bits?    Since x86 is little-endian (and if you were doing to store edx:eax into memory, you'd normally put eax first, at a lower address), my first reading of "first 32" was the low half.  But the low N bits of a multiply don't depend on input bits outside the low N, so the low 32 of your result should be right.  Best to just say high / low, IMO.

Comment: Anyway, the key point here is that the inputs to `mul` *aren't* different sizes.  RAX just has some high garbage in this question, to make sure you understand that.  The manual makes this pretty clear: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul

Comment: Not an exact duplicate: [imul assembly instruction - one operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3818755) answers the question by explaining how `mul` and `imul` work, but doesn't explicitly mention that the high part of RAX is still irrelevant with 32-bit operand-size in 64-bit mode.  That's the confusion here. Maybe [The advantages of using 32bit registers/instructions in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38303333) / [When and why do we sign extend and use cdq with mul/div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36464879)

Comment: Loosely related: but [Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711) - but you're *not* doing a wider operation with garbage in high bits, you're using a 32-bit operation.  The real comparison would be against `mov ecx, eax` (zero extend into RCX) / `imul rcx, rsp` to get the 64-bit result in RCX. Also [Why is imul used for multiplying unsigned numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607)