# Problem in understanding the overflow flag (OF) as defined by the IMUL instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, eflags

I've confusion in why `imul` sets `OF` in the following instructions

```
mov  al, 48
mov  bl, 4
imul bl      ; AX = 00C0h, OF = 1
```

but **NOT** in the below instructions

```
mov  ax, 48
mov  bx, 4
imul bx      ; DX:AX = 000000C0h, OF = 0
```

Comment: A multiply that gives a double width result mathematically cannot overflow.  So, the overflow flag is then used instead to report on the single width result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IMUL` sets the overflow flag when the low half of the result, interpreted as a signed integer of the appropriate size, does not equal the mathematical result of multiplying the two input numbers.

The mathematical result of multiplying 48 by 4 is 192.  The value left in AL after `imul bl` is `C0h`.  As a signed 8-bit integer, that represents the number -64.  Mathematically, 192 and -64 are not the same number, so overflow must be set.

After `imul bx`, the value left in AX is `00C0h`.  As a signed 16-bit integer, that represents the number 192.  So the overflow flag is not set.

Equivalently, the overflow flag is set if sign-extending the low half would yield a different value from the full product.  When you sign-extend the 8-bit value `C0h` to 16 bits, you get `FFC0h`, which does not equal `00C0h`, so overflow is set.  When you sign-extend the 16-bit value `00C0h` to 32 bits, you get `000000C0h`, which does equal the actual 32-bit result, so overflow is not set.

Equivalently, the overflow flag is cleared only if every bit of the high half of the result is equal to the sign bit of the low half.  The sign bit of the 8-bit value `C0h` is 1, but the high half is not FFh, it is 00h, so overflow is set.  The sign bit of the 16-bit value `00C0h` is 0, and the high half is `0000h`, so overflow is cleared.

Comment: TL:DR: `OF` tells you whether you can truncate the double-width full result back to the input width without changing its value.  That's what you want to know if you're using `imul` or `mul`  as part of a sequence of other 8-bit or 16-bit operations like `add`, *without* planning to use the high half of the result (or having a slower version that does.)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The explanation unset my confusion ;)

Answer (score 2):

`OF` tells you whether you can truncate the double-width full result back to the input width without changing its value.  (When interpreted as a 2's complement integer for [`imul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul)<sup>1</sup>, unsigned binary integer for [`mul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul).)
`0xC0` is the bit-pattern for a negative 8-bit number, but `0x00C0` is a positive 16-bit number.

That's what you want to know if you're using `imul` or `mul`  as part of a sequence of other 8-bit or 16-bit operations like `add`, *without* planning to use the high half of the result.
(Or could be useful to fall back to an extended-precision version that does handle the wider size, if the narrow version is fast enough to be worth branching for.)

If you were already going to use the full width of the output, don't check OF/CF; widening multiply can't overflow in the sense of losing any output bits.  The product of two N-bit numbers can always be represented in 2N bits.

---

**Footnote 1**: Including the 2 and 3 operand forms like `imul cx, dx, 123` that don't write the high half anywhere.  Normally you'd use that form for non-widening signed or unsigned math, but if you want to detect when an unsigned multiply wrapped, your best bet is to just use `mul` even though that forces you to use EAX and have the output in EDX:EAX.  See [imulq and unsigned long long overflow detection in C and asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253541/imulq-and-unsigned-long-long-overflow-detection-in-c-and-asm)

Comment: +1, that means imul single operand is useful when optimization is required (operation on lower half only when it represent the true value)

Comment: @dummyaccount: In that case you might use `imul reg,reg` in the fast path, and redo the multiply using the slower `imul reg` in the fallback, on the assumption that you usually stay in the fast path so better to make it faster and not step on extra registers in it.  Of course you need to keep both multiply operands available in case you do need to fall back, which might cost an extra mov in the fast path.  (2-operand imul is 3 uops for operand sizes other than 64-bit (where it's 2 uops) on recent Intel CPUs.  https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/.  Except 8-bit is still fast)