# What would be the hex value stored in eax after executing this snippet?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm starting with assembly language and I can't seem to wrap my head around the mul function. The snippet is:

```
mov eax,0x4
mov ebx,0x2
or eax,ebx
mul eax,ebx
```

So, from what I've understood, First off, eax gets the value 4 and ebx gets the value 2. Then or eax,ebx stores the value 6 to eax (I'm not very sure about this part, please correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm stuck on the mul eax,ebx part. Do I just multiply 6 and 2? Or do I concatenate it? Or do I take their binaries and do something with that?

Comment: There must be some mistake, `mul eax, ebx` is not possible, `imul eax, ebx` is possible though and so is `mul ebx`

Comment: When in doubt, consult the official documentation. It's meant exactly for this purpose :)

Comment: @harold: that is true. But in the assembler I use (Delphi builtin asm), you not only can write it like that, you even should, because in some versions, `mul reg` generates bad code, while `mul eax,reg` doesn't. Same with `div`.

Comment: Yes, `mul ebx` simply multiplies `eax` with `ebx` and stores the result in `edx:eax` (top 32 bits in `edx`). Both `eax` and `ebx` are considered as unsigned (unlike with `imul`).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis oh interesting, what does it do with `mul reg`?

Comment: @harold: don't remember, that was an old version (2011, IIRC). It generated something that worked, but did not do an unsigned multiplication. But some of my code must still work for that version, so I got in the habit of using `mul eax,reg` or `mul rax,reg`. It still compiles in the latest versions. It is a workaround.

Comment: @harold: I vaguely remember: it generated something like mul dx instead of mul edx, or mul r9 instead of mul r9d. It was a bug in one version.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis multi-operand `imul` does non-widening multiplication, so it's signness is irrelevant here since the result is the same in signed or unsigned [Which arithmetic operations are the same on unsigned and two's complement signed numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21475286/995714), [x86 MUL Instruction from VS 2008/2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4040834/995714)

Comment: A question with the same code was asked a couple days ago as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780010/what-is-ebx-register-in-assembly-language, with the same broken `mul eax,ebx`.  But deleted because it wasn't clear what was being asked.

Comment: @phuclv: OK. The low 32 bits are indeed the same.