# Difference between signed and unsigned on bitwise operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, unsigned, signed

Is there any difference between signed and unsigned variables on bitwise operations?
For example,when dealing with unsigned numbers:
`AND 00000111, 00001101`
will result 00000101.

But what would happen when dealing with signed numbers?

Comment: [Which arithmetic operations are the same on unsigned and two's complement signed numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21475286/995714)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming 2's complement is used for signed numbers, operations that care about signedness (ie they are different for the signed and unsigned interpretation of a bitstring) are:

- division
- modulo
- right shift
- comparisons (except equality)
- double-width multiplication (rare outside of assembly)

Operations for which signedness is irrelevant are:

- addition
- subtraction
- negation (`-x` means `~x + 1`)
- bitwise and
- bitwise or
- bitwise xor
- bitwise not (`~x` means `-x - 1`)
- left shift
- multiplication
- comparison (equality only)

Comment: Can you show an example of the difference with the right shift operator between signed and unsigned?

Comment: @user1718294 signed right shifts preserve the sign, unsigned right shifts puts zeroes in the top bits. So `-1 >> 1 = -1` (signed) and `0xFFFFU >> 1 = 0x7FFF` (unsigned).

Comment: Wouldn't a signed left shift preserve the sign bit as well?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes well you could define it that way, but I don't immediately see any uses - forcefully keeping the sign fixed in a left shift only makes any difference when the result would overflow, and that result is then not very useful. Wrapping modulo a power of two at least has some meaning.

Comment: Also, doing anything else breaks the identities `x << 1 == x + x` and `x << 1 == x * 2`, which are probably too important to break.

Comment: `-x` normally just means `0 - x`, not actually `~x + 1`.  e.g. x86's `neg` sets flags based on `0 - x`, not `~x + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned and signed numbers are an interpretation of a bitstring. The `AND` operator doesn't have that notion and works on the single bits. The result will be the same in any way.