# Is it possible to multiply by an immediate with mul in x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, multiplication, immediate-operand

I am learning assembly for x86 using DosBox emulator. I am trying to perform multiplication. I do not get how it works. When I write the following code:

```
mov al, 3
mul 2
```

I get an error. Although, in the reference I am using, it says in multiplication, it assumes AX is always the place holder, therefore, if I write:

```
mul, 2
```

It multiplies `al` value by 2. But it does not work with me.

When I try the following:

```
mov al, 3
mul al,2
int 3
```

I get result 9 in ax. See this picture for clarification:
[image]

Another question: Can I multiply using memory location directly? Example:

```
mov si,100
mul [si],5
```

Comment: `mul al, 2` seems to be incorrectly accepted by MS-DOS DEBUG and treated as if you entered `mul al` (multiplies implicit byte operand `al` by explicit operand `al` and store in implicit destination `ax`).

Comment: There's no immediate `mul`, but there immediate `imul` in 186 and newer.  See [problem in understanding mul & imul instructions of Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783509) .  There's no memory-destination `mul` or `imul` even on the newest CPUs, only memory-source.  There is `imul cx, [si], 5` if you want, though, on 186 and newer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no form of `MUL` that accepts an immediate operand.

Either do:

```
mov al,3
mov bl,2
mul bl     ; the product is in ax
```

or (requires 186 for imul-immediate):

```
mov ax,3
imul ax,2  ; imul is for signed multiplication, but low half is the same
           ; the product is in ax.  dx is not modified
```

or:

```
mov al,3
add al,al  ; same thing as multiplying by 2
```

or:

```
mov al,3
shl al,1   ; same thing as multiplying by 2
```

Comment: The comment in your second code snippet is wrong. After `imul ax, 2` the product is in AX (not in DX:AX).

Comment: Also note that `imul`-immediate is a 3-operand instruction.  So you can use it non-destructively, like `imul cx, si, 1234`.  Most assemblers let you write `imul cx, 1234` as a short-hand for `imul cx, cx, 1234`, similar to writing `vaddps ymm0, ymm1` instead of `vaddps ymm0, ymm0, ymm1`: i.e. when dst = src1.

Answer (score 4):

**Intel manual**

The [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual - Volume 2 Instruction Set Reference - 325383-056US September 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20151025081307/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)
 section "MUL - Unsigned Multiply" column  `Instruction` contains only:

```
MUL r/m8
MUL r/m8*
MUL r/m16
MUL r/m32
MUL r/m64
```

`r/mXX` means register or memory: so immediates (`immXX`) like `mul 2` are not allowed in any of the forms: the processor simply does not support that operation.

This also answers the second question: it is possible to multiply by memory:

```
x: dd 0x12341234
mov eax, 2
mul dword [x]
; eax == 0x24682468
```

And also shows why things like `mul al,2` will not work: there is no form that takes two arguments.

As mentioned by Michael however, `imul` does have immediate forms like `IMUL r32, r/m32, imm32` and many others that `mul` does not.

Answer (score 2):

There's no immediate `mul`, but there is non-widening `imul`-immediate in 186 and newer, and `imul reg, r/m` in 386 and newer.  See @phuclv's answer on [problem in understanding mul & imul instructions of Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783509) for more details, and of course Intel's instruction set reference manuals for mul and imul:

- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul - one-operand widening dating back to 8086, and newer more efficient and convenient forms that don't use DX:AX as an implicit destination.
- https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul - only one-operand widening form that's existed since 8086

There's no memory-destination `mul` or `imul` even on the newest CPUs.

There is `imul cx, [si], 5` if you want, though, on 186 and newer, for 16-bit operand-size and wider.  And on 386, also `imul di, [si]`.

But those new forms of imul don't exist for 8-bit operand-size, so there is no `imul cl, [si], 5`.

On a 386 or newer, it would typically be more efficient to use an LEA for a multiply by a simple constant, although it does cost a bit more code-size.

```
; assuming 16-bit mode
    mov  cx, [si]              ; or better movzx ecx, word [si] on newer CPUs
    lea  cx, [ecx + ecx*4]     ; CX *= 5
```