# NASM and x86_64: Why is there no instruction for multiply by an immediate value?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am interested in understanding the difference between an instruction like `add` and one such as `mul`.

When writing `x86` assembly with NASM, there is an `add` mneumonic which takes an immediate value as an "argument". There is no such equivalent instruction for multiply `mul`. The options for `mul` are either a value obtained from a memory location or a value obtained from another register.

What is the reason for the difference between the two instructions?

I believe it could be due to two reasons:

- **A software reason:** NASM implements the mneumonics for the two instructions differently. Think about it like this: Technically, NASM translates text `.asm` files into binary `.o` files, and it *could* implement one mneumoic per machine instruction, or it could not implement some machine instructions. I guess it could also implement multiple forms of a mneumoic for each instruction. (and arguably does so if you consider there are multiple different forms of each instruction for the combinations of valid operands.)
- So possibly there is a `mul` instruction which takes an immediate value as an operand, but it isn't implemented in NASM.
- **A hardware reason:** (I consider this more likely.) There is a physical `add` instruction which takes an immediate value as an operand. There is no such value for multiply.

I assume my second theory is more likely? (Or possibly there is another reason.)

My only theory as to the details of the reason for why the hardware implementations of machine instructions are different? Multiply is possibly a more complex machine instruction which cannot be completed in a single clock cycle? But why that would mandate that the hardware implementation of each instruction be different? That I cannot explain. In my view, any immediate value could be "registered" in a non-programmable register.

Comment: [There is no `mul` taking a immediate operand](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul)

Comment: What immediate do you want?  Multiplication for lots of small immediates can be handled by `lea` or `shl`, or other instructions & instruction pairs.

Comment: I did read it. Your title is asking `Is there no instruction for multiply by an immediate value?` And your question states `I believe it could be due to two reasons:`, so I'm not sure why you're now saying __I know__.

Comment: @tkausl Will edit the title

Comment: `imul r, r/m, imm` exists.  It's much rarer to need a widening multiply.  Basically a duplicate of [Is it possible to multiply by an immediate with mul in x86 Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20499141) if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @ErikEidt Ah, does this mean that `mul immediate` would be an exact duplicate of `lea`? I am not sure what the relevance of `shl` is, unless this is specifically for multiply by 2? In other words, `lea blaa blaa` would be equivalent to a multiply instruction with an immediate?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Not exactly, but it can be used to implement some kinds of multiplication by immediates.

Comment: The relevance of LEA is tricks like [How to multiply a register by 37 using only 2 consecutive leal instructions in x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46480579).  Or for a single LEA, multiply by 2, 3, 4, 5, or 8, or 9.  (e.g. `lea eax, [rdi + rdi*8]`)

Comment: @PeterCordes I guess this opens up a whole new bag of questions - why is there more than one multiply instruction?

Comment: 8086 legacy of mul/imul (different high half depending on signedness) being so slow in original 8086 that a few instructions before/after isn't a big deal.  Then adding newer instructions for the common case of non-widening multiply in 186 (immediate) and 386 (`imul reg, r/m`).  [problem in understanding mul & imul instructions of Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948058) covers a bit of that.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Different multiplication instructions do different things.  Other instructions perform multiplications but aren't named multiplication instructions because they are meant for other things.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you both I will do some more searching

Comment: BTW, your guess about NASM translating source lines to multiple machine instructions or not could be checked with a disassembler.  `nasm -felf64 foo.asm && objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.o`.  (`ndisasm -b64` only works well on a flat binary).  Unlike MIPS assemblers, NASM doesn't do pseudo-instructions, and x86 doesn't have any spare registers it could use for mov-immediate anyway.  It only accepts source lines that can become a single machine instruction. (It does disentangle `lea eax, [rcx*9]` to `lea eax, [rcx + rcx*8]` for you, though.)

Comment: Anyway, I think phuclv's answer on [problem in understanding mul & imul instructions of Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783509) is probably the best duplicate that covers the whole situation of what's available.

Comment: I was asking specifically what immediate you want to use (because it matters)?  Or maybe you want all of them within some range?

Comment: @ErikEidt Not sure I understand the question? Does this help: `mul 10` ?

Comment: Given a value in `rdi` use `lea rax, [rdi+rdi*4]` to multiply by 5, then `add rax, rax` doubles for 10.

Comment: @ErikEidt Is that likely to be faster than `lea rax, [rdi*10]` or `lea rax, [rdi+rdi*9]`? (Are both of those valid?)

Comment: Neither of those are valid: you'll have to wait for the hardware designers to implement that, so could take a long time, whereas the form I'm showing is already implemented, so will be faster.

Comment: @ErikEidt And it isn't possible to do this? `lea rax, [0 + rdi*10]` ?

Comment: Try it out and see.

Comment: @ErikEidt Next time I have access to the VM - I will do that

Comment: @ErikEidt: "wait for the hardware designers to implement that" is a weird way to explain the problem.  That would take a redesign of x86-64 machine code!  Indexed addressing modes have a 2-bit shift count, allowing multipliers of 1, 2, 4, or 8.  It wouldn't make much sense to include an arbitrary multiplier in addressing modes; that would increase address-generation latency, and we already have imul-immediate as one separate instruction.  Re: multiplying by 10, yes, `x*2*5` is good, as in [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057)

Comment: @PeterCordes, yeah, perhaps my comment was a bit sardonic as the OP continues to ask things that are not currently (and never will be?) supported, but could hypothetically be done.  My bad.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Ah right, I see the sarcasm now.  But Intel syntax especially makes it non-obvious that it's actually a 2-bit shift count, not an integer multiplier.  Of course, they could have just tried their `*10` idea in an online assembler like https://godbolt.org/ or https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I did do this