# Why are there two ways to multiply arbitrary signed numbers in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, instruction-set, risc

If you need to multiply two arbitrary signed numbers in MIPS, is there a reason to prefer:

```
mul $t0 $s0 $s1
```

Or this:

```
mult $s0 $s1
mflo $t0
```

?

I'm finding inconsistent answers online with regard to what each one means. At first glance I would expect the former to be a pseudo-instruction for the latter. (And there's even a web page that claims that.) But looking at the machine code it appears that `mult` is a valid R-type instruction (opcode 0) whereas `mul` has a nonzero opcode (0x1c) and so shouldn't be an R-type, even though it contains 3 registers?!

RISC philosophy says to use pseudo-instructions frequently since we only have limited real instructions. But I'm just not thinking of why you'd need two different ways to multiply. Both affect `lo` and `hi` (using MARS), so you can check for overflow with either. So why the redundancy? Why not just tell everyone to use `mul` all the time?

Comment: (And before anyone asks: I'm not a student. I'm a teacher trying to understand, to head off student questions.)

Comment: _"I'm finding inconsistent answers online with regard to what each one means."_ I'd suggest going by what _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_ says before looking at any online answers.

Comment: FYI there's [cseducators.se] for this purpose

Comment: @phuclv: That's for questions about how to pass knowledge on to students.  This question doesn't belong there, it's a strictly technical question about MIPS multiply instructions, not about how to teach students about them.  (The *Why not just tell everyone to use mul all the time?* is about confusing online search results, not about how to teach students)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mul` is *not* a pseudo instruction. It does *not* modify either the `hi` or `lo` registers that `mult` does. They are different *real* instructions in the instruction set.

In general, we have `a = b * c`

Since multiplying two 32 bit numbers together produces a 64 bit result, in the general case we use `mult` and then get the lower 32 bits of the result with `mflo` and the upper 32 bits with `mfhi`. This allows greater accuracy at the expense of needing an extra instruction [or two] to get the result.

If we only care about the lower 32 bits of the result of the multiply (e.g. array index calculations), we can use `mul` which allows the result to be in a different register from the arguments (in a *single* instruction)

Consider a simple program:

```
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    mul     $v0,$a0,$a1
    mult    $v1,$a2
    mflo    $v0
```

Now, if we assemble it using `mars`, we get:

```
00400000:   70851002    mul     $v0,$a0,$a1
00400004:   00660018    mult    $v1,$a2
00400008:   00001012    mflo    $v0
```

Notice that we have a real `mflo` instruction on line 3. *If* `mul` were a pseudo-op, `mars` would [have to] inject an `mflo $v0` between the `mul` and `mult` lines

---

**UPDATE:**

> That's interesting. And you're right about it not being a pseudo-instruction. (You'd see that when it was assembled, if it were.) But when I use MARS, both mul and mult modify hi and lo. Maybe this is a MARS bug?

Possibly. `spim` *also* modifies hi and lo.

Upon further reflection, this seems logical given the era of the original mips CPU cores (circa 1985) and the [extremely] limited number of gates they had.

But, real mips cores are still alive today. The company is "MIPS Technologies, Inc" and it still existed as of 2017.

The ISA reference manual from the company [AFAICT] has a copy here: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-6.06.pdf

In that document, the `mul` instruction does *not* list changing hi or lo as a side effect.

In *some* document I've seen [I can't recall which], it states [for old/real hardware] that you have to have an intervening instruction between the `mult` and an `mflo` (e.g. a `nop`). The simulators don't require this.

As good practice, I probably wouldn't rely on lo/hi being valid for too long after `mult` and *not* rely on them at all for `mul`, so, for class work, it's a bit of a moot point.

It would be interesting to see what `qemu` does. It's harder to use than `spim` or `mars` [which I prefer] but may be closer to what actual hardware does.

Comment: That's interesting. And you're right about it not being a pseudo-instruction. (You'd see that when it was assembled, if it were.) But when I use MARS, both mul and mult modify hi and lo. Maybe this is a MARS bug?

Comment: this looks similar to [single operand `imul reg` and multi-operand `imul reg, reg[, imm]` in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948058/995714)

Comment: Original MIPS (R2000) had a multiply unit that was only loosely connected to the rest of the integer core.  (See https://doc.lagout.org/electronics/doc/mips/See%20mips%20run.pdf).  Since it took *many* cycles to multiply (or divide), and they wanted integer register modifications to be complete by the WB stage in the 5-stage pipeline, something had to give.  Having special instructions to read/write `lo/hi` let `mult` be super slow and not have to interact with the normal register file except for reading inputs.  (Which aren't allowed to be modified for a few insns after running `mult`!)

Comment: Later MIPS that could interlock instructions on GP integer registers (and had longer pipelines and much higher performance multiply units) were able to usefully introduce a new multiply instruction that improved code-density and reduced overhead of `mflo` instructions.

Comment: @AdamSmith - that's interesting indeed. The "digital design and computer architecture" book (by Harris and Harris) book refers to `mul` as a pseudo instruction.

Comment: @AdamSmith. Also: the ISA reference manual suggests that `lo/hi` are unpredictable after `mul`, so the MARS implementation may be correct. I just don't get why the textbook suggests that it's a pseudo instruction (together with less authoritative references online, e.g. https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~csci226/MIPS/SPIM.pdf).